# How to select multiple columns, sum one column and group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a table named `example`, with columns `user_id`,`date_start`, and `activity`

I need to select `user_id`, `date_start`columns and count unique `user_id` and then group by `user_id` and `date_start`.

Table Data:

```
  ----------------------------------
 | user_id | date_start | activity  |
 |---------|------------|-----------|
 |  1      |2021-04-01  | CATIA     |
 |  1      |2021-04-05  | CATIA     |
 |  1      |2021-04-02  | CATIA     |
 |  1      |2021-05-01  | CATIA     |
 |  1      |2021-05-02  | CATIA     |
 |  3      |2021-05-02  | CATIA     |
 |  3      |2021-05-03  | CATIA     |
 |  4      |2021-05-05  | CATIA     |
  ----------------------------------
```

This Query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(d.date_start, 'yyyy-MM'), d.user_id
from (select d.user_id,  date_start,
         count(*) over (partition by user_id) as cnt,
         row_number() over (partition by FORMAT(date_start, 'yyyy-MM') order by FORMAT(date_start, 'yyyy-MM') desc) as seqnum
  from planner d
 ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

I need my code show like this:

```
  ---------------------
 | date_start | total  |
 |------------|--------|
 | 2021-04    | 1      |
 | 2021-05    | 3      |
  ---------------------
```

Comment: Your desired results don't align with what your query is trying to do, you want a count of each unique date but your query has no *total* column and has *user_id* that's not in your desired results?

Comment: I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this? :

```
select FORMAT(d.date_start, 'yyyy-MM') date_start
     , count(distinct user_id) total
from planner d
group by FORMAT(date_start, 'yyyy-MM')
```

Comment: `user_id` count must be unique on a specific year and month